# Inflating view in view hierarchy in runtime (on user demand)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, model-view-controller, view

I have tried to look throughout similar questions, but haven't found any solutions or best practices.

My question is following.

I have custom view, for instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/bottom_indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is layout for my custom view (not final there will be some difference  , just to make it more readable).

Here you can see `CirclePageIndicator`. It is hardcoded that it will be this type of indicator in view.
What do I need ?
I am looking for the best way to make able user to select desirable indicator specifying value of my custom view attribute, and than in runtime check user choice and inflate such type of indicator

I have some ideas how to do this, but don't know what is better both for performance and clean code.

1. Just leave only `ViewPager` (and whatever I want to have in my custom view) and than in runtime just problematically create indicator object depending on choice and ad it to the view hierarchy
2. Use `ViewStub` and than I also have to specify id of desired view to be inflated.
3. Just have all types of indicators but with "View.GONE" attribute, but I think it is bad idea.

Please help to solve this problem in the most correct and elegant way.

I will be grateful for any advice, explanations and examples.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: see LayoutInflater/Factory and/or LayoutInflater/Factory2 interfaces

Comment: in LayoutInflater.Factory[2]#onCreateView() you can then use LayoutInflater#createView(String name, String prefix, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you provide some example as answers

Comment: yes Activity#getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this) or Activity#getLayoutInflater().setFactory2(this)

Comment: Thank you for answer , I mean to post as an answer on  to my question. 
As for question, this way is not acceptable,because this requires to set custom view factory in Activity, but I am creating library,of course I can note that method should be called, but this is bad practice I think, better just allow specify desired indicator type in xml without understanding how does it work under the hood for user

Comment: `Factory` and `Factory2` is just an interface and can be implemented by **any** class, also i don't understand what is a bad practice? you define the indicator type in xml anyway...

Comment: actually when using factories your indicator name can be anything: for example <my-super-indicator>, it does't have to be something like <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator>, also you can use any custom attribute to add your custom data to the indicator

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you please put everything together and post as an answer.

Comment: no, since I don't  know how you want to use it in your library

Comment: just an example, as you have commented, I think it would be better for other to read an answer rather than comments